# Function for setting a streak of strings in a Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with artist names in one column, I want to find how many times the artists repeats through the column.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Artist":["Tim Maia","Jorge Ben","Tim Maia",
                             "Tim Maia","Jorge Ben","Roberto Carlos",
                             "Roberto Carlos","Roberto Carlos",
                             "Roberto Carlos",
                             "Dire Straits"]})
```

I've already had some success using [itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), so that was my starting point for this function:

```
def artist_streak(df):
    # created to check if artists repeats, not returned
    artists = []
    # this will be returned
    streaks = []
    # since each observation counts, makes sense to start at 1
    count=1

    for row in df.itertuples():
        # artists[-1] in an empty list will raise IndexError:
        try:
            # Checking if current artist is the same as the last appended
            if artists[-1] == row.Artist:
                    count += 1
                    artists.append(row.Artist)
                    streaks.append(count)
            else:
                # The artist does not repeated  
                count = 1
                artists.append(row.Artist)
                streaks.append(count)
        # Here we set things right for the first iteration
        except IndexError:
            artists.append(row.Artist)
            streaks.append(count)


    return streaks
```

Usage:

```
df["Result"] = artist_streak(df)
```

My concerns about this code are:

**1. The artists list [ ]:**

It is the way I could think of checking the current iterator item vs. the previous one, I don't know if it is a good way.

**2. The try/except part:**

As it addresses the specific case of list artists being empty, I don't know if it hurts performance (i.e. there is a faster way to do it).

Any other suggestions on how to make it faster, cleaner, or even pythonic will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starter, your implementation is too tightly tied to your data, making it not reusable for other kind of dataframe where you would want to count streaks. If you provided a column (`pd.Series`) to the function instead, it would be much more versatile; allowing calls such as `count_streak(df.Artist)`, `count_streak(pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3])` or even `count_streak('abcdccbdddbbbbcaaacbddba')`.

Doing so, you would remove the need for `itertuple` and favor regular iteration. This would ease the use of `enumerate` to check for the previous element:

```
def count_streak(sequence):
    streaks = []

    for index, element in enumerate(sequence):
        if not index or sequence[index - 1] != element:
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
        streaks.append(count)

    return streaks
```

Much simpler. But this is all without taking into account the wonderful `itertools` module and its [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function. It will make group of consecutive data that evaluate equals, yielding both the value, and the entire group. The other advantage being that any iterable will be accepted:

```
def count_streak(iterable):
    return [
        i for _, g in itertools.groupby(iterable)
        for i, _ in enumerate(g, start=1)
    ]
```

Since you wish to stay in `pandas`' world, you also have a `groupby` method available on `DataFrame`s and `Series`. But contrary to `itertools.groupby` that stops at each boundaries, `pandas`' `groupby` return all occurences of similar data even if some are discontinuous. But you can make [use of `cumsum` and `cumcount`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626699/5069029) to get an equivalent and vectorize these operation instead of a slow python loop. This would require a `pandas.Series` as parameter, though, not any iterable:

```
def count_streak(serie):
    return serie.groupby((serie != serie.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

usage being

```
df['Streak'] = count_streak(df.Artist)
```

---

And since you commented on performances, here is a small benchmark comparing the approaches. I’ve thrown in a couple extra approaches, out of curiosity. The code to produce the results is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

def python_streaks(sequence):
  streaks = []
  for index, element in enumerate(sequence):
    if not index or sequence[index - 1] != element:
      count = 1
    else:
      count += 1
    streaks.append(count)
  return streaks

def python2_streaks(sequence):
  streaks = [1] * len(sequence)
  for index, element in enumerate(sequence):
    if index and sequence[index - 1] == element:
      streaks[index] += streaks[index - 1]
  return streaks

def numpy_streaks(sequence):
  streaks = pd.Series(np.ones(len(sequence), dtype=int))
  for index, element in enumerate(sequence):
    if index and sequence[index - 1] == element:
      streaks[index] += streaks[index - 1]
  return streaks

def itertools_streak(iterable):
  return [
    i for _, g in itertools.groupby(iterable)
    for i, _ in enumerate(g, start=1)
  ]

def pandas_streaks(serie):
  return serie.groupby((serie != serie.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

for size in range(8):
  size = 10**size
  for name in ('python', 'python2', 'numpy', 'pandas', 'itertools'):
    setup = 'import pandas as pd;from random import choice;from __main__ import {}_streaks as streaks; df = pd.DataFrame({{"Artist": [choice("abcde") for _ in range({})]}})'.format(name, size)
    elapsed = timeit.timeit('df["Streaks"] = streaks(df.Artist)', setup=setup, number=1000)
    print(name, size, elapsed)
```

And the results are (I stopped pure Python loops as they were taking too much time):

[image: Benchmark log scale]

or, without using log scale on the Y-axis:

[image: Benchmark linear scale]

So depending on the amount of data you wish to process, either itertools (up to 10000ish elements) or pandas version is better.

Comment: Hello Mathias, thanks for your answer. Since your answer brings more than one valid improvement, I would like to share the insights I've got.
itertuple_streak(df):
 `413 µs ± 1.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`
sequence_streak(df.Artist):
`79.3 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`
serie_streak(df.Artist):
`1.06 ms ± 46.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: Which syntax is cleaner may be controverse opinion, since  count_streak(serie) is almost a oneliner. But I think `count_streak(sequence)` looks better and it's faster

Comment: @CelsoPereiraNeto See updated answer for performance benchmarks, pandas has overheads so it is slower for fewer data to process, but really faster for larger amounts.

Comment: I'm unsure why you didn't use `itertools.groupby`, it also is written in C so is likely to be faster than python/python2. `def python3_streaks(sequence):
 for _, g in itertools.groupby(sequence):
  yield from (i for i, _ in enumerate(g, start=1))`

Comment: @Peilonrayz Because I was contemplating the `pairwise` recipe too much to check for consecutive values that I completely forgot it was the perfect tool for the job. It is by far faster than any other approach until 10000ish elements where `pandas` starts to keep up. I’ll include it in the timings. Do you want to write an answer with this approach?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Nah, it'd be better integrated with you answer :)